# Why do some approximations give exact results?

Tags: moment-of-inertia, approximations

The moment of inertia of a sphere of mass $M$ and radius $R$ can be calculated exactly (meaning, with certainty) using integrals. The formula we get is $\frac{2}{3}MR^2$. However, there's an other approach: you take the moment of inertia of a solid ball of radius $R$ and substract from it the moment of inertia of a solid ball of radius $R-dr$, with the fact, that what remains (a sphere) has a mass equal to $M$, in mind. However, by using this method, you stumble accross something like $(R-dr)^5$. By convention, you expand it and neglect every component proportional to $dr^k, k>1$, because while $dr$ is really small, $dr^2$, $dr^3$ etc. are even smaller, nearly zero. By doing so you eventually get $I = \frac{2}{3}MR^2$. Now, what bugs me about it: why one method which doesn't use approximations (integration) gives us the same result as the one which neglects something? Sure, $dr^2$ is unimaginably small, but why is it perfectly reasonable to fully ignore it?

Comment: Are you sure that your "approximation" is not just mimicking the definition of the Riemann integral, and doing the limits in there explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inertia of a solid sphere is $\frac{2}{5} m R^2$ and that of a *thin* shell sphere is $\frac{2}{3} m R^2$.

By subtracting one solid sphere from an another and taking $\mathrm{d}r \rightarrow 0$ you exactly calculate the integral for the shell. There is no approximation here.

A *thick* walled sphere with $\mathrm{d}r > 0$ has different mass moment of inertia from a *thin* walled sphere. This is reflected by a  factor that comes out of $R^5 - (R-\mathrm{d}r)^5$.

If I assume $\mathrm{d}r > 0$ but small enough for $(\mathrm{d}r/R)^2\approx0$ (with a 1st order taylor series) I get

$$ I = \frac{2}{3} m R (R-\mathrm{d}r) $$

Now this represents the inertia of a thin walled sphere, but not *inifinesimally* thin. Only finite thin section.

So depending on the level of *approximation* you choose it represents a different thing as it relates to the relative thickness of the shell to the radius.

In real life any calculation **not of thick wall** is an approximation because you cannot have an a wall of zero thickness. So $\frac{2}{3} m R^2$ is never an exact value.